# Algorithm to modify a matrix and set columns and rows to zero

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix, time-complexity

This is technically a code challenge.
I was asked an interesting question at an interview and am hoping for some insight as the best answer I could come up with was O(2n^2) - n-squared category, but still pretty much brute force.

Let's say you have a matrix that's M by N size ( an array of arrays (`int[][]`) )

```
1 2 4 3 1
0 5 3 7 7
5 8 9 2 8
6 7 0 8 9
```

If a cell contains a Zero, then set that entire row and column to zero.
Making the result:

```
0 2 0 3 1
0 0 0 0 0 
0 8 0 2 8
0 0 0 0 0
```

What is the fastest and/or best way to do this?

---

My own answer is to iterate the entire array of arrays, keep track of rows and columns to zero out, and then zero them out.

```
public void zeroOut(int[][] myArray){
    ArrayList<Integer> rowsToZero = new....
    ArrayList<Integer> columnsToZero = new....

    for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){ // record which rows and columns will be zeroed
        for(int j=0; j<myArray[i].length; i++){
            if(myArray[i][j] == 0){
                if(!rowsToZero.contains(i)) rowsToZero.add(i);
                if(!columnsToZero.contains(j)) columnsToZero.add(j);
            }
        }
    }
    for(int row : rows){ // now zero the rows
        myArray[row] = int[myArray.length];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        for(int column: columns){ // now zero the columns
            myArray[i][column] = 0;
        }    
    }
}
```

Is there a better algorithm? Is there a better data-structure to represent this matrix?

Comment: You have O(N^2) data to process, so obviously it cant be done faster than O(N^2). Stick with what you have.

Comment: You have to visit every cell to check for presence of 0's so you can't do better than O(m*n)... you're approach seems intuitive to me

Comment: What about making a HashMap out of each row and column (you end up with M + N HashMap(s)) and then for each one of them asking: `if (hmap.contains(0)){/*zero out the column or row it represents*/}`

Comment: @RichardPlunkett M x N matrix (capital N). M*N=n number of data to process. OP said `O(2n^2)`, you said `O(N^2)`

Comment: Instead of an `ArrayList` you should use a `HashSet` since the `contains` method will have O(1) cost instead of O(n). For zeroing the rows, you can use a fixed array to reduce memory cost.

Comment: You can't really reduce the time complexity of the entire function. However, you can reduce the number of comparisons (this is normally the main time waster anyway) by not using if statements to check every cell (i.e. after finding a 0, don't check cells in the same row/col later)

Comment: but you'd need to check them later so you know which other ones to zero out

Comment: @EliteOctagon You should zero out the whole row and column when you find the a 0. Then not check those again later, by not checking again later you won't zero out rows/cols for the 0s which the function has added

Comment: Also, since ArrayList#contains() is `O(n)` your algorithm is `O(M*N*max(M,N))` (for square matrix this is O(n^1.5) where n=M*N)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no one really came up with a significantly faster/better algorithm so far, so this one seems to be it. Thanks for your input everyone.

```
public void zeroOut(int[][] myArray){
    ArrayList<Integer> rowsToZero = new....
    ArrayList<Integer> columnsToZero = new....

    for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){ // record which rows and columns will be zeroed
        for(int j=0; j<myArray[i].length; i++){
            if(myArray[i][j] == 0){
                if(!rowsToZero.contains(i)) rowsToZero.add(i);
                if(!columnsToZero.contains(j)) columnsToZero.add(j);
            }
        }
    }
    for(int row : rows){ // now zero the rows
        myArray[row] = int[myArray.length];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        for(int column: columns){ // now zero the columns
            myArray[i][column] = 0;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: This solutions throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :) Please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by taking two `int` but the only condition is the no of rows and cols should less than or equal to 32. You can do the same with greater than 32 but you have to take array of ints.

So the logic is :

- take two ints i.e. `row` and `col`
- traverse the matrix if `matrix[i][j] = 0` than set the corresponding bits in the `row` and `col`
- after traversal traverse again and set the `matrix[i][j] = 0` if corresponding bit of either `row` or `column` is set.

The time complexity is same **`O(N^2)` but it is memory efficient**.  Please find my code below .

---

Check whether the `array[row][col] == 0` if 0 than set the corresponding bit in `r` and `c`.

```
        int r = 0, c = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
                if (array[row][col] == 0) {
                    r = r | (1<<row);
                    c = c | (1<<col);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now if either of the bit is set than make the cell to 0.

```
  for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <7; col++) {
            if (((c&(1<<col))!=0) || ((r&(1<<row))!=0)) {
                array[row][col] = 0;  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as my implementation, but no code, can you explain what you mean by setting bits? I'm unfamiliar

Comment: @EliteOctagon check my edit. The time complexity is same but this is much more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What about splitting the matrices into equal smaller matrice parts and calculate the deteriminant, so that you can predict that there is a zero within this matric part.
And then only use the brute force mechanism to this preselected matrices to determin
in wich row or column the zero is.

The determinant is just a suggestion maybe you can use some other kind of linear algebraic 
algorithms and rules to predict a zero value

UPDATE:

if you use Quicksort concept to organize temporay every row. Then you have just to loop until the first none zero element occurs.
You need to remember during sorting process which column index was associated with the 0

Means

```
 1 2 6 0 3
```

Quciksort (

```
 0 1 2 4 6
```

When you remember the column index you now directly know which row to fill with 0 and which column,

Average of Quicksort ist O(n log n) Worstcase n * n

Maybe this already improves the overall complexisitiy.

Comment: I'm pretty interested in your logic, can you write some code and/or explain it some more?

Comment: No not today. In the beginning i just thourgt about QuickSort. Which comes from two sides an splits the problem into smaller peaces. Then i thought how to split it in a correct way. So i thought about some algebraic functions. Maybe at sunday i could present you some solution. Real intersting problem.

Comment: I think i will try it until sunday evening. Maybe i could give some inspirations even if i had no solution at all until now. I think we'll meet here again than.

Comment: I think the time complexity is O(N^2). Because the the partition that you are using here takes O(N) and for N rows it is O(N^2). So the main trickiest part of the question is how do you remember the rows and cols which i think the best possible way is bit set.

Comment: Yeah right. You need to remember the column index. You have to do Quicksort for each row means in average O(n log n * m). At least i think that it is this way

Comment: @ChristianSchack it is worse than `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Yes in deed. But i don't think my complexisitity calculation is correct.

Comment: There must be some kind of 2 dimensional sorting to organize a matrix in the appropriate way. I don't know yet. I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question and have developed a solution for it. 
I am hoping I can get some feedback for the code about how it's better/worse and it's runtime.
Pretty new to all this :)

```
public static void zeroMatrix(int[][] arr1)
{

    ArrayList<Integer> coord = new ArrayList<>();

    int row = arr1.length; 
    int column = arr1[0].length;
    for(int i=0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if(arr1[i][j]==0)
            { 
                coord.add((10*i) + j);
            }       
        }
    }

    for(int n : coord)
    {
         int j=n%10;
         int i=n/10; int k=0;
        int l=0;
        while(k<row)
        {
            arr1[k][j]=0;
            k++;
        }
        while(l<column)
        {
            arr1[i][l]=0;
            l++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used HashMap.See if this can help in any way

```
import java.util.*;
class ZeroMatrix
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int mat[][]=new int[][]{{0,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,0}};
HashMap<Integer,Integer> ht=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
{
if(mat[i][j]==0)
ht.put(i,j);
}
}

//Set the Respected Rows and colums to Zeros 
Set set=ht.entrySet();
Iterator itr=set.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
Map.Entry m=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
int i=(Integer)m.getKey();
int k=(Integer)m.getValue();
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
{
mat[i][j]=0;
}
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
{
mat[j][k]=0;
}
}

//Printing the Resultant Zero Matrix 

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
{
 System.out.print(mat[i][j]);
}
System.out.println();
}
}
}
```